# MvvmCross common binding does not work

Tags: data-binding, touch, xamarin, mvvmcross

This is actually *pretty trivial* thing, however, I've bumped into it already several times and every new time was spending *plenty of minutes* to find out why such simple binding to properties (with MvvmCross) *does not work*! So, I hope that would help anyone.

The situation (is pretty simple):
(just **a view with some property** I am going to bind to ViewModel (in this example - for Touch)).

```
public class MyView : MvxViewController
{
    protected string SomeValue
    {
        get; set;
    }

    private void SomeInitializationMethod()
    {
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyView, MyViewModel>();
        // binding to "this"
        set.Bind().For(x => x.SomeValue).To(x => x.ViewModelSomeValue);
        set.Apply();
    }
}
```

So, in this case the property **does not bind** and you can see "**Failed to create target binding for from ViewModelSomeValue to CurrentContacts**" message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the cause of the problem is just some simple word: "**public**".
As MvvmCross uses reflection for databinding, it expects the property to bind to is public and honestly says "I could not get to it".

```
protected string SomeValue
{
    get; set;
}
```

*That happened for me several time just because of Resharper using and it was adding the property modifier automatically to "**protected**".*

Good luck!